# authenticate user on server side for Swing clients using kerberos/spnego

Tags: swing, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas, spnego

I am using kerberos protocol to authenticate users for Java Swing applications. I am able to successfully authenticate at the client side, but having problems when getting the user credentials and roles on the server side, I have got ejbs which require certain roles to create those ejbs.

jboss-app.xml looks like

```
 <jboss-app>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/spnego-server</security-domain>       
    <loader-repository>paymenttracker:loader=paymenttracker.ear</loader-repository>
 </jboss-app>
```

The client class calling Subject.doAs(s, lv); 
lv is a class which extends PrivilegedExceptionAction.

On the server side login-config.xml in jboss server got the following setting

```
     <application-policy name="spnego-server"><authentication> 
    <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required" >
<module-option name="storeKey">true</module-option> 
<module-option name="debug">true</module-option> 
<module-option name="useKeyTab">true</module-option> 
<module-option name="keyTab">file://c:/ker/tem.keytab</module-option> 
<module-option name="principal">HTTP/ws6421.ebrd.com</module-option> 
<module-option name="doNotPrompt">true</module-option> 
<module-option name="isInitiator">false</module-option> 
</login-module></authentication>
</application-policy>
```

getting the following error :

```
16:09:28,990 INFO  [STDOUT] Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true
ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is file://c:/kerberos/ws6421.keytab refreshKrb5Config is false pr
incipal is HTTP/ws6421.my.com tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is fa
lse
16:09:29,087 INFO  [STDOUT] principal's key obtained from the keytab
16:09:29,087 INFO  [STDOUT] principal is HTTP/ws6421.my.com@MY.COM
16:09:29,088 INFO  [STDOUT] EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=0000: A9 DD 6C AB C5 D3 A0 9D   C8 4
4 18 52 78 3E AB 82  ..l......D.Rx>..
16:09:29,094 INFO  [STDOUT] Added server's keyKerberos Principal HTTP/ws6421.ebrd.com@MY.COMKey Version 0key
 EncryptionKey: keyType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: A9 DD 6C AB C5 D3 A0 9D   C8 44 18 52 78 3E AB 82  ..l......D.Rx>..
16:09:29,095 INFO  [STDOUT]             [Krb5LoginModule] added Krb5Principal  HTTP/ws6421.my.com@MY.COM t
o Subject
16:09:29,098 INFO  [STDOUT] Commit Succeeded
16:09:29,135 ERROR [SecurityInterceptor] Error in Security Interceptor
java.lang.SecurityException: Denied: caller with subject=Subject:
        Principal: HTTP/ws6421.my.com@MY.COM
        Private Credential: Kerberos Principal HTTP/ws6421.my.com@MY.COMKey Version 0key EncryptionKey: ke
yType=23 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: A9 DD 6C AB C5 D3 A0 9D   C8 44 18 52 78 3E AB 82  ..l......D.Rx>..


 and security context post-mapping roles=null: ejbMethod=public abstract services.ejb.login.SBLogin services.e
jb.login.SBLoginHome.create() throws javax.ejb.CreateException,java.rmi.RemoteException
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.checkSecurityContext(SecurityInterceptor.java:368)
        at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.process(SecurityInterceptor.java:243)
```

Comment: Is your `krb5.ini` correct? Did you try to create a login context with that keytab. That must succeed before you try JBoss.

Comment: basically i haven't changed anything in the jboss and krb5.ini which is working for spring application. I have added the login module in login-config.xml in jboss server. and in jboss-app.xml defined <security-domain>java:/jaas/spnego-server</security-domain>. when a call is made to the PrivilegedExceptionAction (run method)implentation class an ejb look up is made where it fails. When trying to do the ejb look up Krb5LoginModule class is involved and the debug messages printed. Also how will the server get the logged in username ?

Comment: Have you verified that the client is actually sending the security token? Do you have a security manager working? This is weird: Denied: caller with subject=Subject:... Something is misconfigured.

Comment: you might be quite right, the client seems to read the ticket but not sure if it is passing it to the server, it looks the principal is null on server side, do I need to configure org.jboss.security.negotiation.NegotiationAuthenticator somewhere? Can you please let me know how to ensure the ticket is passed, I am using jboss 5.1.0. when I debug Krb5LoginModule subject is empty

Comment: Install Fiddler and inspect the HTTP request. It should contain the `WWW-Athenticate` information.

Comment: do I need to use GSSCredential & GSSContext class to pass the ticket?

Comment: I even used SpnegoHttpURLConnection to a dummy url in the application do the initial connection which works fine but the ejb look up fails, it looks like the javax.ejb.SessionContext is not set and subject not send as part of the ejb look up, can you please help , I am kind of stuck now.

Comment: The server must need to have both: You can use a Windows-compiled `cURL` binary. It has SSPI support which will create the ticket for sure. Please make sure that you receive a 200 with a WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate Y,, from the server back.